# A word with maximal number of subwords

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $W$ be a cyclic word of length $n$ in a 2-letter alphabet $\{0,1\}$. It is clear that it has at most $n^2$ different subwords (because the number of subwords of length $i$ is at most $n$ for each $i$) and that the actual number of subwords is less than $n^2$ (because the number of subwords of length $1$ is not $n$, but $2$). What is the maximal possible number of subwords as a function of $n$ and what are words where this upper bound is achieved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you take a [de Bruijn sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_bruijn_sequence) of length $2^k$, then you have every length $k$ 
sequence precisely once. This implies that the number of subwords is maximal, since each subword of length $\geq k$ is determined uniquely by its prefix, and each subword of length $ < k$ occurs (with equal frequency). So this achieves the upper bound when $n=2^k$.

Comment: A similar analysis applies for general n.  If m is the smallest integer such that every subword of n of length m is unique, then the number of unique subwords total is at least n(n-m+1).  Thus m will
always be at least floor(log n).  But it should be possible to find a length n fragment of a Debruijn word which will achieve minimal m, as well as attain the largest number of distinct subwords of smaller length.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.09.15

Comment: You can go the other way too. If you have a prescribed multiplicity for each word, you can form a corresponding directed (Eulerian) multigraph in an obvious generalization of the de Bruijn construction. Then you can use the matrix-tree and BEST theorems to enumerate the sequences with these multiplicities. If you google "generalized de Bruijn" and restrict to site:mathoverflow.net you'll find one or two posts of mine on this topic.

Comment: Here is a nice paper on subword complexity that gives the same answer:
http://www.csd.uwo.ca/faculty/ilie/IJFCS04.pdf .